# Distribution of sum of independent but not i.i.d. lognormal variables?

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution, approximation, distribution-identification

I am trying to find the distribution of the following variable Z:

$X_i$ are each independent with Lognormal distribution ($\mu_i, \sigma^2_i$), $X_i \in L^2$ forall $\forall i$

Z = $\sum_i cX_i$ where $c$ is some non-negative scalar

The [Fenton-Wilkinson approximation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238529/the-sum-of-independent-lognormal-random-variables-appears-lognormal/238566#238566) does not work since the r.v.s are not i.i.d and thus I'm not sure how to find the distribution so I can compute probabilities.

Comment: There is no closed form.  Sometimes, geostatisticians invoke a "principle of conservation of lognormality" to approximate such linear combinations with a lognormal distribution, knowing YMMV.  The value of $c$ is irrelevant, btw, because it can be absorbed in all the $\mu_i.$  The shape of the sum is determined primarily by how much the $\sigma_i$ vary and whether any of them are extreme (watch out for values greater than about 0.6, typically).