# Sum of exponential of MVN dimensions

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, moment-generating-function

Consider drawing N random variables $x_{i}$ for $1\leq i \leq N$ from a multivariate normal with $\mu = (\mu_1, .. \mu_i, .. \mu_N)$ and $ \Sigma_{N \times N} = [\sigma_{ij}]$ (equivalently, N correlated Gaussian RVs).

I am interested in calculating the probability that
$\sum_i \exp\{ x_i \} < c$ for these given parameters.

So, what is the probability that the sum of the exponential of MVN RVs will be less than a given value?
This might also be framed in terms of log-normal random variables.

Comment: Then the wording is wrong: one is drawing $N$ correlated univariate Gaussians. In which case the sum is a [sum of log-normals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238566/7224).

Comment: The question text is very unclear, can you please fix it?